# How to create an "onscroll" state and an idle state for the same element?

Tags: jquery, scroll, onscroll

**I would like to know how to make a position:fixed element change style when scrolling and then go back to its "idle" state when the user stops scrolling.**
Until now, I have only found scripts that change the element as soon as scrolling is detected but then it does not go back to its previous state
My objective is to have a little character at the center of the screen that has a running state when the user is scrolling down, and an idle state when the user stops scrolling.
Here is what I got so far (after having searched this website):

EDIT:thanks to @TCHdvlp I could modify my document but I still can't get it to work :S

Could you tell me what I am missing?

Here is what I have:

```
    <head>


        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Knock Knock Megaman</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


        <style type="text/css">

        #wrapper{
            height: 1000px;
        }
        .fixedImg{
            position: fixed;
            content:url(examples/images/meg1.png);
            top:50%;
            left: 50%;
        }
        .slideUp {
            content:url(examples/images/Megaman2.png);
            position: fixed;
            top:50%;
            left: 50%;
           }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="divimage" class="fixedImg">
        </div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        //when the begining of a scroll occurs on the document
        $(document).on("scroll",(function(){
            //remove the fixed property via the class
            $('#divimage').removeClass("fixedImg").addClass("slideUp");
        });
        //when the end of a scrolling occurs
        $(document).on("scrollStop",(function(){
            //fix the element via the fixed class
            $('#divimage').addClass("fixedImg").removeClass("slideUp");
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Jquery, not just mention it in the tags ;) And, use css classes.

Create a fixed class, let say, `fixedImg`. Add this class to `#divimage` and, you have imported jquery, use it !!

The idea here is to say, "While I'm scrolling on the page, remove the fixed attribute. Then, if the scroll has stopped, re-attach the fixed class".

```
//when the begining of a scroll occurs on the document
$(document).on("scroll",(function(){
    //remove the fixed property via the class
    $('#divimage').removeClass('fixedImg');
});
//when the end of a scrolling occurs
$(document).on("scrollStop",(function(){
    //fix the element via the fixed class
    $('#divimage').addClass('fixedImg');
});
```

And, of course, in the css

```
.fixedImg { position : fixed; ..... }
```

And, of course bis, remove this

```
#divimage : {position:fixed}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!
I edited my file but still couldn't get it to work :S
Could you tell me what I'm missing ?

Comment: You are swapping between `.fixedImg` and `slideUp` classes. They both are `position:fixed;`. There is no point doing that !! Remove the `position:fixed;` from `.slideUp` class